# Combination type problem power of 2

Tags: combinations

How many different ways could I factor $2^{2n}$ so that each factor is a even power of $2$? So for example if I have $2^{12}$ and I want to write it as 3 factors of even powers of $2$ I could do $2^{2} \cdot 2^4 \cdot 2^6$.

Comment: Hint: How many ways can you partition a natural number as a sum of natural numbers.

Comment: Surely $2^0=1$ is not an even power of two, right?